# Can Can has_many through Explanation help need badly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, has-many-through

Dear All (especially Ryan, thank you for this great work),
I am just going completely nut with something that probably is just really stupid, but that for the life of me I can't wrap my brain around and solve it.

I am trying to use Can Can, for authorization, and I set it up correctly on everything except (and this is my issue, on a specific thing, that apparently works fine, but that I am not sure if I am doing it right or not - actually I think I am not able to prove that it doesn't work properly).

Let's see if I am able to explain clearly what I am doing:

I have two models (User and Album), that are connected through a third model Share:

## (A)  User Model

```
has_many :albums, :dependent => :destroy # ownership
has_many :shares, :foreign_key => "shared_user_id" #, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :shared_albums, :through => :shares
```

## (B)  Album Model

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :shares, :foreign_key => "shared_album_id", :dependent => :destroy
has_many :shared_users, :through => :shares
```

## (C)  Share Model

```
belongs_to :shared_user, :foreign_key => "shared_user_id", :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :shared_album, :foreign_key => "shared_album_id", :class_name => "Album"
```

Now, in my Ability class, what I would love to do is restricting the actions that can be performed, by a specific user on the (C) Share Model.

In my app, an user can create an album, and after he can add other users to that album (this users are the only one that can access the specific album). In addition, every user that is part of an album,can also add on it new users.

All this is done giving to the users present in the album, the ability to create share (the Share model relate the User and the Album model).

Now the big question, how I restrict the ability to add(create) share to a specific album, only to that users that are part of that album(through share)?

If for example I have:

users => id (1,2,3,4) [a total of 4 users in my app)

albums => id (45,32) [a total of 2 albums in my app)

shares => (album 45 => [user (1,2,3)] ; album 32 => [users(1,4)]) [a total of 5 shares in my app]

How I can say in the Ability class that on album 32(for example), just the user 1 and 4 can add(create) new share(add new user), and that instead the user 2 or 3 they can't?

I already restricted the ability for the user 2 and 3 to anyway access the resource album 32 (I did that on the Album class level), but I want be sure that for whatever reason the ability to create users is restricted also.

What I have until now in my Ability Class is:

```
def initialize(user)

  (A) ALBUM LEVEL

     # (1) Every User can create Album, without restrictions
     can :create, Album   

     # (2) Only the user that own the Album can manage it
     can :manage, Album, :user_id => user.id 

     # (3) The Album can be read by all the users that are part of that specific album
     can :read, Album, :shares => {:shared_user_id => user.id}

     # (4) The Album can be read by every user if the privacy attribute is false
     can :read, Album, :privacy_setting => false


  (B) SHARE LEVEL

     # (1) Only the user that own the Album can manage all the shares for the album
     can :manage, Share, :shared_album => {:user_id => user.id}

     # (2) The other users (in the album), can just manage themself (their share)
     can :manage, Share, :shared_user_id => user.id

     # (3) The Share in the album can be read by every user if privacy is false (just read)
     can [:read], Share, :shared_album => {:privacy_setting => false}
     cannot [:create,:destroy,:delete], Share, :shared_album => {:privacy_setting => false}


 #### (X) CRUCIAL POINT CREATE NEW SHARE
     can :create, Share, :shared_album => {:shared_users => {:id => user.id}}

 end
```

Is the condition in (X)CRUCIAL POINT the right condition to allow just users that are already part of the album, to add new user to the album???

This is completely driving me insane.

Thank you to everybody, and especially to who will be able to let me understand a bit more of all this.

Best
Dinuz

Answer (score 0):

Your ability.rb seems fine to me.

Your crucial point does the following:

A user can create a share if there is a shared album for that share, and if the the current user is included in that shared album's shared_users.

One thing to keep in mind, though. Since you check the shared_album of a share when authorizing, you must first set it before attempting to authorize.

For example:

```
@share = @albums.shares.build
authorize :create, @share
```

The example above will set the `shared_album_id` of a share, so that you can authorize it.

```
@share = Share.new
authorize :create, @share
```

This won't work, since the share does not yet have an album.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Arjan! What are you suggesting it's already in place(my fault cause I didn't post nothing of my controllers)! Actually in the new action I have the following: @album = Album.find(params[:album_id]) and @share=@album.shares.build. I just want be sure that my schema is correct! I appreciate your answer, but it's not what I was looking for. Thanks